# iterate over a list of chemical names using ChemSpiPy to get canonical smiles

Tags: python

I have list of chemical names called Phenolics

```
Phenolics
0   Dihydroquercetin 7,30-dimethyl ether
1   Artelin
2   Esculin 7- methylether (methylesculin)
3   Esculin
4   Scopoletin (7- hydroxy-6- methoxycoumarin)
5   Axillarin
6   Esculetin
7   Isoscopoletin
8   6-Beta-D-glucosyl-7- methoxycoumarin
9   5,40Dihydroxy- 3,6,7,30- tetramethoxyflavone
10  Apigenin
11  Luteolin-7-O- glucoside
12  Magnoloside
13  Penduletin
14  Quercetagetin
15  Quercetagetin-3,6,7- trimethyl ether
16  Quercetin
17  Quercetin 7,30- dimethyl ether (Rhamnazine)
18  Scoparone
19  Skimmin
20  Umbelliferone
21  Apigenin 40-methyl ether
```

and I would like to run a search on chemspipy to obtain the canonical smiles of these chemical names.
I tried

```
for result in cs.search(Phenolics):
print(result.smiles)
```

and it doesn't work, I get no results.

Comment: The print statement should be indented within the for loop. But did you try to `print(len(cs.search(Phenolics))`?

Answer (score 0):

I can not test it because I have no API key, but this should search for the name and give you a result about it. How to then get a canonical SMILES from that result is another question I can't answer:

```
from chemspipy import ChemSpider

cs = ChemSpider('<YOUR-API-KEY>')

Phenolics = ['Artelin', 'Esculin', 'Axillarin']
for name in Phenolics:
    result = cs.search(name)
    print(name, result)
```

Comment: I actually tried this it doesn't work

Comment: Did you insert your api key? What's the error?

Comment: Yes I did have the key. I ran it again and got Phenolics Results(Created) but I am not able to see it

Comment: when I check to see what's in result I get Results([])

Comment: Then the ChemSpider database might not have an entry for that name. Try it with someting simple, like 'ethanol'.

Comment: it works when I just put in the chemical names but once I place it in a loop it doesn't work.

Comment: Hm, perhaps there is a rate limit to the API? You can try to use time.sleep(5) inside the loop to wait a few seconds between the calls. There might also be a parameter for search that waits automatically the required time.

Comment: thanks ill try that, but it seems like I have to find a different package/API to get this to work